# Importing class in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

```
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
```

do i need to write the above import class every time when i create a new controller?In laravel 4.2 it does automatically

is any other way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "In laravel 4.2 it does automatically"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do. Your app is under the namespace `App;`, so if you want to use the `Input` class, but you don't say `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input`, `PHP` will try looking for it under your namespace `App;` and an exception will be thrown since the class you're looking for probably won't be there.

Comment: thanks. how the app.php file  in config folder works we are defining all class inside that file like(Input,Validator,...,..) will this command 'use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input' looks for input class inside app.php file ? how the flow works?

Comment: @srivat1 which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel version 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Those are not a mandatory class.
When ever you are using those facedes you have to add

There is one way i know.

1. class something like CustomController
2. Add the all the common classed in that controller.
3. Now for every controller you can extend the new CustomController